# Ruby class methods

Tags: ruby, oop

Can some one please help me with this problem.
I try this code and i keep getting a method error as seen in the bottom

```
 class Song
    @@play = 0;  #class variable must be define before use
    
    def initialize(name, artist, duration)
        @name = name
        @artist = artist
        @duration = duration
        @plays = 0
    end

    def play
        @plays += 1 #same as @plays = @plays + 1
        @@play += 1
        "This song: #@plays plays. Total #@@play plays"
    end

end

class SongList
    Max_Time = 5*60

    def self.is_too_long(song)
        return song.duration > Max_Time
    end
end

song1 = Song.new("Bicyclops", "Fleck", 260)
p song1.duration

p SongList.is_too_long(song1)
```

ruby_ex03.rb:49:in `<main>': undefined method` duration' for #Song:0x000000000605f338 (NoMethodError)

Comment: Song has no method "duration", an instance variable is just that--not an accessor method.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, instance variables and methods are distinct things, and there is no way* to access instance variables from outside the class they belong to. If you want to make your instance variables accessible, you need to define accessors in your class

```
def duration
  @duration
end
```

Fortunately, this pattern is so common that Ruby provides a shortcut for us. Simply put this in your class body

```
attr_reader :duration
```

---

*Technically, we can use reflection to access instance variables from anywhere, but conceptually you should think of them as inaccessible. Those techniques are advanced and useful only in special circumstances.